# UNIDRV - read a GPD feature from the configuration plugin

Tags: windows, driver, thermal-printer

I must make a change in an existing UNIDRV custom printer driver.

I must be able to read the user selection of a custom feature, from the GPD, into the configuration plugin.

I can't find anything that tells me of a function, or a variable, that holds the contents of the features/options set from the GPD.

I would be happy to just being able to read the value, so I can add it in the private DEVMODE and send it to the calling application.

**More detailed reasoning, and alternatives that would help:**

- The driver was created with features in GPD that gradually got moved into the configuration plugin, but in the same section (CommonUIProp). Sadly the UI does not have any other tabs in which to place all the properties.
  When I tried to move this feature in the configuration plugin, removing it from GPD or making it `*ConcealFromUI?: TRUE`, the driver crashed - and I am guessing it is because, without any printer features in GPD, the section does not get created, so adding to it in the configuration plugin fails.
- I considered adding some dummy feature in the GPD, but bosses say no because users would be confused.
- There is one feature I could have, but with only one value - and then the GPD gets sneaky smart and doesn't show it. Therefore still crashes when I remove the feature I need to move in UI.
- The callbacks that I have used from GPD have a `commandCallbackOptions` in the rendering plugin, which is great to use for the rendering as well as the more complex printer commands, or those which depend on features from the configuration plugin. 
  Such a callback would be great in configuration plugin, or 
  A way to access the private DEVMODE from associated software (for analytics) after setting the values in this function, would also be a solution
- One of the features that currently resides in the configuration plugin requires numeric user input - integer from -10 to 10. I could not find any way to make a user input, other than combo, in GPD - If I could it would solve all problems.

I can post the GPD or pieces of it - nothing special compared to the driver sample.

I hope someone can have a suggestion with how to read the feature selection, from configuration plugin - since GPD creates the structure, it must be communicating with it, documentation and samples so far have offered no ideas.

We plan to move to v4 and proper tabs, but that will be a bigger project not prioritized yet. It should solve this problem... But I would like a solution before that remote date.